# To find the equation of the plane

Tags: vectors

I need to find the equation of the plane given the following two conditions:

1. The plane passes through two points $R(1,0,1)$ and $Q(2,1,0)$, and
2. is parallel to the intersection of the two planes $x+y+z=5$ and $3x-y=4$.

My approach so far:

- I found $\vec{RQ}$, i.e. $Q-R = (1,1,-1)$ (don't know if it will be useful or not...)
- Then I took the normal vectors of the two given planes, which are $n_1=(1,1,1)$ and $n_2=(3,-1,0)$. Then I took their cross product 
  $$n_1 \times n_2 = \langle 1,3,-4\rangle.$$
- I assumed $x=0$ and solved for $x,y$ and $z$. I got
  $$x=0 ; y=-4 ; z=9.$$

I reached till here and I am very, very confused what to do ahead. I took the cross products of the normal seeing the information given in [here](http://www.netcomuk.co.uk/~jenolive/vect18d.html), which shows how to find the equation of line given two planes. Please guide me. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let equation of plane be $Ax+By+Cz+D = 0\;,$ Then plane passes through $R(1,0,1)$

So it satisfy the above equation

So we get is $A.(1)+B.(0)+C(1)=0$.

So equation of plane is $$A(x-1)+B(y-0)+C(z-1) =0..............................(1)$$

Now that plane also passes through $(2,1,0)$.

So we get $$A(2-1)+B(1-0)+C(0-1)=0.................................(2)$$

Now Given $2$ planes $x+y+z=5$ and $3x-y=4$

Now Intersection of these $2$ plane $x+y+z=5$ and $3x-y =4$ is a line.

So let $a,b,c$ be the direction of  required line . Since required line is lib both the plane

So $a+b+c=0$ and $3a-b+c=0$

So we get $$\displaystyle \frac{a}{1+1} = \frac{b}{3-1} = \frac{c}{-1-3}\Rightarrow \frac{a}{2} =\frac{b}{2} =\frac{c}{-4}$$

Now Put $z=0$ in these two plane, we get $\displaystyle x=\frac{9}{4}\;\;, y= \frac{11}{4}$ and $z=0$

So Intersection of above two plane is line,

Whose equation is $$\displaystyle \frac{x-\frac{9}{4}}{2} =\frac{y-\frac{11}{4}}{2} =\frac{z-0}{-4}$$

Now the line is parallel to the plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$

So we get $$2A+2B-4C=0\Rightarrow A+B-2C=0..........................................(3)$$

Now elimination of these three equation, we get a equation of plane.

So $$\displaystyle \begin{vmatrix}
 x-1& y & z-1\\ 
 1& 1 & -1\\ 
 1 & 1  & -2
\end{vmatrix} =0\Rightarrow x-y-1=0$$

Comment: In the elimination of the equations, how did you get x-y-1=0? i tried to solve it and i am getting x-y=0. Oh i see, i got it! It's because of x-1... Sorry :p